# How to get main Activity class or class name of my application?

Tags: android

How to get main Activity class or class name of my application?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get your launcher activity use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)

```
getLaunchIntentForPackage
```

On this Intent call `getComponentName` and from the returned CompomemtName call `getClassName`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to Lee for explaining how to get the classname, here's the code:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
```

Comment: The application's className would just output some garbage like **com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication**

Comment: launchIntent.getComponent() could return null, because not all lauchend intents contains the respective component.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getComponent()

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me in Kotlin:

```
callingActivity::class.simpleName
```

or in Java:

```
activity.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get the Activity class name in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val packageName = context.packageName
val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
val className = launchIntent?.component?.className ?: return null
```

How to get the Activity class from the class name in Kotlin:

```kotlin
return try {
   Class.forName(className)
} catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
     e.printStackTrace()
     null
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just set a variable in my main activity like so... `public static Activity activity = this;` then I can reference it from anywhere using: `MainActivity.activity`.

You can also set it in the onCreate() method, just set up the variable at the top of your main activity class like this `public static Activity activity;` then in the onCreate() method just add `activity = this;` anywhere.

This will work for any class that extends Activity, for example `public class MainActivity extends Activity` however you can call the variable from any class even if they don't extend Activity.

Hope this helps.